# How to extract different groups of 4 rows from dataframe and unstack the columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, stack

I am new to Python and lost in the way to approach this problem: I have a dataframe where the information I need is mostly grouped in layers of 2,3 and 4 rows. Each group has a different ID in one of the columns. I need to create another dataframe where the groups of rows are now a single row, where the information is *unstacked* in more columns. Later I can drop unwanted/redundant columns.

I think I need to iterate through the dataframe rows and filter for each ID *unstacking* the rows into a new dataframe. I cannot obtain much from *unstack* or *groupby* functions. Is there a easy function or combination that can make this task?

Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```
2_SH1_G8_D_total;Positions tolerance d [z] ;"";0.000; ;0.060;"";0.032;0.032;53%
12_SH1_G8_D_total;Positions tolerance d [z] ;"";-58.000;"";"";"";---;"";""
12_SH1_G8_D_total;Positions tolerance d [z] ;"";-1324.500;"";"";"";---;"";""
12_SH1_G8_D_total;Positions tolerance d [z] ;"";391.000;"";"";"";390.990;"";""
13_SH1_G8_D_total;Flatness;"";0.000; ;0.020;"";0.004;0.004;20%
14_SH1_G8_D_total;Parallelism tolerance  ;"";0.000; ;0.030;"";0.025;0.025;84%
15_SH1_B1_B;Positions tolerance d [x y] ;"";0.000; ;0.200;"";0.022;0.022;11%
15_SH1_B1_B;Positions tolerance d [x y] ;"";265.000;"";"";"";264.993;"";""
15_SH1_B1_B;Positions tolerance d [x y] ;"";1502.800;"";"";"";1502.792;"";""
15_SH1_B1_B;Positions tolerance d [x y] ;"";-391.000;"";"";"";---;"";""
```

The original dataframe has information in 4 rows, but not always. Ending dataframe should have only one row per Id occurrence, with all the info in the columns.

So far, with help, I managed to run this code:

```
with open(path, newline='') as datafile:
    data = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')
    for row in data:
        tmp.append(row)

# Create data table joining data with the same GAT value, GAT is the ID I need
Data = []
Data.append(tmp[0])
GAT = tmp[0][0]
j = 0
counter = 0
for i in range(0,len(tmp)):
    if tmp[i][0] == GAT:
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter == 2:
            temp=(tmp[i][5],tmp[i][7],tmp[i][8],tmp[i][9])
            
            
        else:
            temp = (tmp[i][3], tmp[i][7])

        Data[j].extend(temp)
            
    else:
        Data.append(tmp[i])
        GAT = tmp[i][0]
        j = j + 1

# for i in range(0,len(Data)):
#   print(Data[i])

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outputfile:
    writedata = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=';')
    for i in range(0, len(Data)):
        writedata.writerow(Data[i]);
```

But is not really using pandas, which probably will give me more power handling the data. In addition, this `open()` commands have troubles with the non-ascii characters I am unable to solve.

Is there a more elegant way using pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you're doing a "partial transpose". Is this what you want (referenced from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567587/pandas-partial-transpose))?

### Sample Data

With unequal number of rows per line

```
  ID  col1  col2
0  A   1.0   2.0
1  A   3.0   4.0
2  B   5.0   NaN
3  B   7.0   8.0
4  B   9.0  10.0
5  B   NaN  12.0
```

### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import io

# read df
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
ID   col1    col2
A      1      2
A      3      4
B      5      nan
B      7      8
B      9      10
B      nan    12
"""), sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

# solution
g = df.groupby('ID').cumcount()
df = df.set_index(['ID', g]).unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b+1}' for a, b in df.columns]
```

### Result

```
print(df)

    col1_1  col2_1  col1_2  col2_2  col1_3  col2_3  col1_4  col2_4
ID                                                                
A      1.0     2.0     3.0     4.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
B      5.0     NaN     7.0     8.0     9.0    10.0     NaN    12.0
```

### Explanation

After the `.set_index(["ID", g])` step, the dataset becomes

```
      col1  col2
ID              
A  0   1.0   2.0
   1   3.0   4.0
B  0   5.0   NaN
   1   7.0   8.0
   2   9.0  10.0
   3   NaN  12.0
```

where the multi-index is perfect for [`df.unstack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html).

Comment: Indeed it worked perfectly Bill! I only need to drop the empty and redundant columns, do a bit of making up rearranging them and job done beautifully using a minimum amount of code! THANKS!